# Automatically detect type of array [] and refer to right method for sorting manipulation

Tags: c#, arrays, types

(code in C# without built-in Net.System.Collection objects)

I'm trying to get solution where I create generic array which can be any type such as INT, STRING, CHAR, FLOAT and etc

I want to detect automatically type of items and array and send to right function (int, string or char)

note: I send Object[] array of, for example, numbers, and I want to detect what array type I got Int[], String[] and etc..

Mean: Object[] arr = { 1,4,3,5,6} , so I have detect that its INT[] array
Object[] arr = { 'dadas', 'eret', 'rwer' } , detect that its String[] array

and etc..

for example:

```
    public Boolean Check2Items<T>(int item1, int item2)
    {
        return (item1 > item2);

    }

    public void Check2Items<T>(string item1, string item2)
    {
         ....
    }

    public void Check2Items<T>(char item1, char item2)
    {
        ....
    }

    public static Object[] SortArr(Object[] arr)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < arr.Length; index++)
            {
                var item = arr[index];


                for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if(Check2Items<int>(arr[index], arr[j]))  < -- **here a problem**
                    {
                        SwapItems(ref arr, index, j); <- this just for example - ignore
                    }

                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null; // if any problem occurred, return null array
        }

        return arr;
    }
```

I can't think for solution about array type and items type..

is it possible?

hope I have asked untestable question :9)
thank you very much for help..

Comment: There's already a generic interface called [`IComparable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=net-5.0). If `SortArr` was properly generic and constrained the array to types that implement that interface, you could write far less code. (Unfortunately, `SortArr` is broken because it's declared to accept `Object[]` which means it could contain an `int` followed by a `Color`, and how do you meaningfully plan to compare those?)

Comment: Is there any reason you're accepting `Object[]` rather than making your `SortArr` method generic, e.g. `public static T[] SortArr<T>(T[] arr)`? At the moment, you could have an array which mixes strings and integers, for example.

Comment: As we're trying to tell you, you're going about this wrong because you're throwing all of the type information away, to the point that someone can call your method after constructing `Object[] arr = {1, Color.Red, "fruitflies"}`. The type system isn't being allowed to do it's job properly to *ensure* that the array only contains one type of thing.

Comment: `Array.Sort(arr);` will actually sort your array using the default comparer, unless you had an specific way of sorting in mind

Comment: I decided to choose Object[] because I can build array of anything and use same variable for testing and not create 10 variables of different types..

I don't want to use built-in function like .sort, or anything which uses System.Collections.Generic functions or method like List<T> and so..

and I want to give one type of array,  or INT or STRING and etc, not mixed arrays as @Damien_The_Unbeliever says..